# How to run a JavaFX application without main method in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, program-entry-point

I have created and complied several javaFX applications without main methods in NetBeans and InteliJ IDEA. I have also compiled successfully a simple JavaFX application (see the code below) without a main method in windows command line.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloJavaFX extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        stage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

So I believe it is possible to run JavaFX applications without main methods in eclipse too. But when I try it, I fail and eclipse indicates could not find a main method. I have added JavaFX jar file to my eclipse IDE and I can compile and run JavaFX applications with main methods in eclipse. So I guess I should add some path or address to help eclipse to run it, but I don't know how.

My question is "what else should I do to make eclipse compile and run JavaFX applications without main method?"

Comment: @Carcigenicate Not for javafx application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139115/running-javafx-app-without-main-method

Comment: @Oleg There's a special case specifically for JavaFX apps? That seems bizarre.

Comment: Actually the Application class and JVM create main method for JavaFX applications so it is not necessary to add it manually.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, I admit that I also learned about it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually reading the question " Can't run JavaFx code from Eclipse" and its answers helped me to figure out how to run a JavaFX application without main method. 
First we add the main method and run it once as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
```

Then we comment the main method out. Now the eclipse IDE run configuration is automatically set to run the application even without the main method.

Thanks @Oleg for directing me to the abovementioned question.
Now, if nobody has any other answer, I announce the question as duplicate.